# Extract Users list from Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group

I have a list of groups in AD, I want to know if there exists a script to extract these group members?

Or tools of manager AD

thank

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you're looking for is Get-ADUser

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx